# Java Firebase error "NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/StrictHostnameVerifier"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, firebase

I have a very simple servlet program running normally on google app engine. Now when i add firebase object to make a child value updation call it shows server error 500 on appengine and on local apache tomcat it also shows some error.
Here is my code

```
package com.example.appengine.helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException,FirebaseException  {


    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello, world");
    Firebase fire = new Firebase("https://fiery-fire-0.firebaseio.com/");
    fire.child("hello").setValue("Nothing is in here");   
  }
}
```

here is the error when running it on apache tomcat

```
    Exception in thread "TubeSockReader-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/StrictHostnameVerifier
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.verifyHost(WebSocket.java:287)
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.createSocket(WebSocket.java:271)
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(WebSocket.java:306)
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(WebSocket.java:30)
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(WebSocket.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.StrictHostnameVerifier
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    ... 6 more
```

On running it on google app engine it simply says

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Kindly help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version of your http client library doesn't have the (now deprecated) class StrictHostnameVerifier.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/StrictHostnameVerifier.html

Try manually including httpclient 4.0.1 instead of "latest" (although it should appear in 4.5.1 according the docs).

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Although it was showing in the docs of 4.5.1 that StrictHostnameVerifier class exists but it was not there and moreover my firebase jar was itself dependent upon 4.0.1 and was getting downloaded automatically. But when i removed that jar and manually downloaded and added it to m2 repo it started working.

Comment: And i got a new problem. That code is working fine when i am deploying it on my localhost using Apache Tomcat server but it still returns the same error when deploying it on Google App Engine. Does anyone have got any idea why it is happening? Kindly help me !!!